Overlay a tikz drawing when using includepdf
When I display 1-page music on the web (or as a PDF preview) I want to limit the (free) use of the music by placing a white triangle as per the image below (here it is shaded, just to be clear);

(This music is not a 1-page piece, but will work as an example.)
The code for this is
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\def\mftri{\mbox{}\vskip12cm
      \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw[red,fill=black,opacity=0.3] (0,0) --++ (17,0) --++ (0,12) --cycle;
       \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\mftri}]{\MusicPagesPath/01367/pdf/01367.pdf}
\end{document}

N.B. The \MusicPagesPath is a shortcut to where I keep the PDFs. For testing you can use any full-page PDF. (I didn't know how to include a file in the post.)
While the triangle appears, I would like more control such as the left corner starting further left/down, and the bottom side further down.
I managed to get the right side "out in the margin" (even if the current value of 17 in the MWE will have it aligned perfectly with the right side margin), but I cannot move the left corner, or the bottom, further below.
Typically I'd like something like the red triangle below (for display, it can easily be filled with white later);

I'm sure my code is not the best and there might be a better approach.
Anyone who can assist? TIA

you can use e.g. example-image-a4 for your mwe. how secure is this meant to be? because I doubt very much this will stop somebody from using your music for free if they want to. the included pdf will still be there. at most you will prevent the less technically inclined from accessing it.

This is the initial step. The PDF is then rasterized and converted back to PDF. It will be impossible to extract anything from the resulting PDF.

You could use \AddToHook{shipout/foreground} to place some TikZ shape as overlay on every page, like in the following example. But as already noted in the comments, this is not secure as you can still select the text underneath the white shape (which might not be too critical here with musical symbols that are probably hard to copy from the PDF anyways).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages, tikz}

\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{
        \fill[white]
            (current page.south east) --
            (current page.south west) --
            (current page.east) -- cycle;
    }
}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{example-image-a4}

\end{document}


(Shape in red for reference:)

Note that this might require multiple compilation runs to have a coordinates at the right position.

If you only need the shape on single pages, you can use \AddToHookNext{shipout/foreground} (as recommend by cfr) which will only place the contents to the following page. You can create a custom command to reduce repeated code. You can use the pages option to select single pages or a range of pages from your PDF files.
To shift the shape, use the shift option. For example ([shift={(1cm,1cm)}]current page.south west) would shift the relevant coordinate (current page.south west) by 1cm to the right and to the top.
Taken together, you could do something like the following to add a shape on page 1 and 4 of a certain PDF:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages, tikz}

\newcommand{\ProtectNextPage}{
    \AddToHookNext{shipout/foreground}{
        \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{
            \fill[white]
                ([shift={(-2cm,2cm)}]current page.south east) --
                ([shift={(2cm,2cm)}]current page.south west) --
                ([shift={(-2cm,0cm)}]current page.east) -- cycle;
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\ProtectNextPage

\includepdf[pages=1-3]{example-image-a4}

\ProtectNextPage

\includepdf[pages=4-]{example-image-a4}

\end{document}


Is it possible to add this to only one page? The full document is a series of 'includepdf' where only some should have the triangle. Could also the triangle be moved up, like in my red 'drawing'? Thanks.

@mf67 \AddToHookNext instead of \AddToHook and \fill[white,yshift=5cm]... to shift up by 5cm.

@mf67 See my edit where I added the suggestion of cfr along with the idea to create a custom command to reduce repeated code.

@JasperHabicht Thank you! But, when adding \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} something happens that moves and crops the triangle to the margins again. Can this be prevented with some code?

@mf67 With remember picture and overlay used as options, you might need to compile several times until everything has shifted correctly. Did you try this?

@JasperHabicht Yes, even after many compilations it remains the same. It seems a4paperdoes something strange with the borders.

@mf67 maybe the PDFs that you insert have a different page format than A4. I think in this case the page format is overridden, but too late. So when the shape is produced, A4 is used as defined by \geometry, but later the page format is changed. Not sure though.
